# Может this ссылаться на функцию?

Tags: javascript

```js
let user = {
  name: 'hello'
};
user.d = function(){

function sayHi() {
    return this.name;
}
let result = sayHi();
return result
}

console.log( user.d() )
```

1. Объявили объект **user**
2. У него есть свойство анонимная функция в которую вложено функция **sayHi**
3. У функции **sayHi** есть **this** он может ссылаться на анонимную функцию ( т.к функцию можно представить как объект  ) и она ( анонимная функция ) оборачивает **sayHi** ?
4. **this** может перепрыгнуть через анонимную функцию чтобы получить результат ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По порядку.

`this` может ссылаться на функцию:

```js
function a(b,c,d) {
  return 0;
}

a.e = function() {
  console.log(this.toString());
};

a.e();
```

`this` внутри функции зависит от того, как функцию вызывают, а не от того, где она находится.

`this` не может "перепрыгнуть" через анонимную функцию. `this` может "перепрыгнуть" через стрелочную функцию.

Comment: this  может ссылаться на функцию если записано как свойство ?

Comment: @user349791 да, если я правильно Вас понял :)

Comment: понимаю Вас я сам себя иногда не понимаю :)

Comment: получается вот такая конструкция получит undefined  function a(b,c,d) {
  console.log(this.toString());
} a();

Comment: @user349791 Нет. `this` в таком случае - `window`.

Comment: я имел ввиду если у нас стоит ''use strikt'' ?

Comment: если мы вызываем функцию через call или apply мы вызываем ее как метод объекта ?

Comment: @user349791 да.

Comment: да это ответ на ''use strikt' или  call или apply ?

Comment: @user349791 call или apply

Comment: жаль я думал 2 вопроса правильные и еще немного ...

Comment: если мы вызываем функцию через call или apply то первый аргумент this будет ссылаться на ближайший объект ?

Comment: посмотрите  последний комментарий верный ?

Comment: @user349791 Я не понимаю, что значит "ближайший объект". `this` в функции полностью определен тем, как функция вызывается (кроме случая стрелочной функции). Мы, по-моему, идем по кругу.

Comment: ясно, если что извините :((